# Minor MYSQL DB upgrade on GCP

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

There is a bug on the Mysql 5.7.14 regarding [password hash](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87722) and has been fixed on version 5.7.19. But the Mysql in the GCP doesn't have any option to do a minor upgrade. So can anyone suggest how to go about this issue?

Comment: As states in Google's documentation about [minors version of MySQL on CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/db-versions#minor_version_support) it will be updated on the next maintenance cycle.

Comment: Is it possible to ask GCP support to do it for us?

Answer (score 2):

Version 5.7.25, which includes the fix for this bug, will be in the next maintenance release later this month.

Comment: Can you please give us an exact date? Its kind of blocking our process, so if you could provide us an estimate, it would be great.

Comment: hey @akhilkrishna, I suggest that if you have a support package to open a support ticket on https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/role-based-support#case_management . you may get this kind of information there

Answer (score -2):

No you cannot do minor upgrades by yourself in[Cloud SQL becasue it is a fully managed service by Google](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) and all updates and upgrades are done behind the scenes for their customers instances. [These updates can be done at any time during the next maintenance cycle](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/db-versions#minor_version_support). However, you can control the day and time and specify a maintenance window for the instance in question.

[When you specify a maintenance window](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-window-2ndgen), Cloud SQL will not initiate the updates outside of that window. This way you can specify the window when there is less or no traffic on your applications which help reduce the disruptive side effects of that maintenance. Maintenance usually takes between 1-3 minutes for the new update to be pushed and the instance become available again.

To specify a maintenance window:

1- Go to the project page and select a project.

2- Click an Instance name.

3- On the Cloud SQL Instance details page, click Edit maintenance preferences.

4- Under Configuration options, open Maintenance.

5- Configure the following options:

**Preferred window.** Set the day and hour range when updates can occur on this instance.

**Order of update.** Set the order for updating this instance, in relation to updates to other instances. Set timing to Any, Earlier, or Later. Earlier instances receive updates up to a week earlier than later instances within the same location.

[read more on it here.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/set-maintenance-window)